# Cloning object (Drag and drop) Flash As3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do I make a clone of a movieclip after it has been dragged, and make the clone appear where the dragged movieclip was before being dragged?

This is what I have so far:

```
movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);

function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
movieClip_1.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_2);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
movieClip_1.stopDrag();
}
```

Also I would also like to know how to make a reset button, to reset the dragged and dropped objects on stage

Comment: You can enable the Export for Actionscript context menu option on the library symbol used by movieClip_1. Once you do that, you can easily create a new instance and copy the x,y coordonates. ...

Comment: After you Export movieClip_1 for actionscript as MovieClip_1 (convention is to use a capital first letter on a class name), you can do something like this in ```fl_ReleaseToDrop_2```: ```movieClip_1.stopDrag();
//create a new instance of the library symbol - it assumes you've set the linkage/Export for Actionscript name as MovieClip_1 (watch the M)
var duplicate:MovieClip = new MovieClip_1();
//copies the mouse coordinates -> these are the global stage coordinates
duplicate.x = event.stageX;
duplicate.y = event.stageY;
//add the movieclip to the main stage 
addChild(duplicate);```

Comment: Use OOP and doing this will be easy. Time to evolve.

Comment: Thank you George, your answer helped. However I still need to figure out how to add a reset button, and it would be nice if the movieclip did not dissappear while being dragged.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza you have 30k rep and should know this, but please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @null You've got a point. I left the notes a comment as I didn't have time for a detailed answer, but wanted to help a little bit. I've not added the notes as a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the symbol you want to make a duplicate of in the **Library Panel**, go to **Symbol Properties** (by right clicking the symbol and selecting **Properties**) and enable **Export for ActionScript**

[image: Flash Symbol Properties]

As a symbol example, I've created a plus symbol and named the symbol Plus.

Once you've done that, you can easily create a new instance of this symbol:

```
addChild(new Plus());
```

Note that `Plus` is the same you gave the symbol in the Symbol Properties,
so if you name your symbol MovieClip_1 in library and it's exported for actionscript the code would look like this:

```
addChild(new MovieClip_1());
```

If you do this, you'll notice the symbol will be placed at 0,0 so the next thing to do is set the x,y position of the new instance. First you need to create a variable you can re-use for this instance:

```
var newPlus:MovieClip = new Plus();
```

Then you can access it's `x` and `y` properties, just like any other MovieClip.

Since you're using the `MOUSE_DOWN` event to create a duplicate, you can use [MouseEvent's stageX and stageY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#stageX) properties:

```
function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var newPlus:MovieClip = new Plus();
   newPlus.x = event.stageX;
   newPlus.y = event.stageY;
   addChild(newPlus);
}
```

Just need to start dragging:

```
function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var newPlus:MovieClip = new Plus();
   newPlus.x = event.stageX;
   newPlus.y = event.stageY;
   addChild(newPlus);
   newPlus.startDrag();
}
```

Of course, need to listen for the stage `MOUSE_UP` event to stop dragging.
For that, we can make the variable storing a reference to the latest duplicated clip outside of the `MOUSE_DOWN` handler. This way, whenever a new clip is added, it will be accessible/visible from the `MOUSE_UP` handler too, so dragging can stop. The catch is to check if a new clip has been aded first, because a user may click on the stage without creating a duplicate.

Here's a commented snippet:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

//a reference to the latest/most recently cloned movie clip
var latestClone:MovieClip;

plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPlusPressed);

function onPlusPressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //make a new instance using the linkage/Export for ActionScript name
    latestClone = new Plus();
    //copy mouse position to movie clip position
    latestClone.x = event.stageX;
    latestClone.y = event.stageY;
    //add it to the stage
    addChild(latestClone);
    //start dragging it, instead of the symbol manually placed on stage
    latestClone.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageReleased);

function onStageReleased(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //if there was a clone already made/dragged
    if(latestClone != null){
        //then release it
        latestClone.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Notice that I've named a single plus symbol placed manually on stage `plus`.
So the instance on stage is `plus`, the symbol/class name is `Plus`:

[image: Symbol instance name]

You can run this [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/Plus.swf) and download the [zipped xfl Flash source here](http://lifesine.eu/so/Plus.swf)

**Update** Based on your comment bellow, turns out it's not that complicated to make the duplicated instances draggable. This can be setup in 3 steps:

1. Add a `MOUSE_DOWN` event handler for the cloned instance. In theory you could re-use the existing handler, but you would need to have a way of differentiating the movie clip clone source and cloned instances. It will be cleaner to have a separate handler, used only by the cloned instances
2. Set the `latestClone` reference to the currently clicked cloned instance: this way the `onStageReleased` handler can be re-used to also stop dragging of the cloned instances
3. start dragging

Based on the previous example code using the Plus symbol, an updated snippet looks like this:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//a reference to the latest/most recently cloned movie clip
var latestClone:MovieClip;

plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPlusPressed);

function onPlusPressed(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //make a new instance using the linkage/Export for ActionScript name
    latestClone = new Plus();
    //copy mouse position to movie clip position
    latestClone.x = event.stageX;
    latestClone.y = event.stageY;
    //add it to the stage
    addChild(latestClone);
    //start dragging it, instead of the symbol manually placed on stage
    latestClone.startDrag();
    //add a separate MOUSE_DOWN event handler for the cloned instance
    latestClone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClonedPlusPressed);
}
//event handler for a cloned instance
function onClonedPlusPressed(event:MouseEvent):void{
    //set the latest clone to be what's currently clicked (MouseEvent's current target)
    //for more details on target/currentTarget and event bubbling see http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html
    latestClone = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);//event.currentTarget return an Object and latestClone is a MovieClip, therefore we cast the currentTarget Object to a MovieClip type

    //start dragging
    latestClone.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageReleased);

function onStageReleased(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //if there was a clone already made/dragged
    if(latestClone != null){
        //then release it
        latestClone.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much George! I managed to follow your instructions, and made it work the way I wanted to, except making the clones become draggable, but I figured out how to manage that with the code you posted, so my question is answered.

Comment: Glad the answer is helpful. It's not difficult to make the clones draggable. I've added an updated snippet above, explaining how it works